Docker: fail to resolve: RUN uv sync --frozen --no-cache
So, for context:
I am trying to start working on a FastApi proj using UV framework, which is great. I am using Python and a Windows computer. Now, the app is still straightforward and runs well on local. When trying to build the image using Docker, however, an error pops up, saying:
=> ERROR [stage-0 5/5] RUN uv sync --frozen --no-cache                                                                                             0.4s 

[stage-0 5/5] RUN uv sync --frozen --no-cache:
0.330 /bin/sh: 1: uv: not found

Dockerfile:11

   9 |     # Install the application dependencies.
  10 |     WORKDIR /app
  11 | >>> RUN uv sync --frozen --no-cache
  12 |
  13 |     # Run the application.

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c uv sync --frozen --no-cache" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127

My Dockerfile contains:
FROM python:3.11

# Install uv.
COPY --from=ghcr.io/astral-sh/uv:latest /uv /uvx /Scripts/

# Copy the application into the container.
COPY . /app

# Install the application dependencies.
WORKDIR /app
RUN uv sync --frozen --no-cache

# Run the application.
CMD ["/app/.venv/Scripts/uvicorn", "run", "src.main:app", "--port", "80", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

I also have a screen shot of my Visual Studio Code setup but it has all of the same information that's in the text above.
I changed the original Dockerfile, because in UV documentation the Dockerfile looks this, but I guess the bin folder only applies to IOs, and for windows its called Scripts, so I changed lines 4 and 14 from /bin to /Scripts (I don't think that's the problem)
Can someone have any idea on what can be happening? I will appreciate any help you can provide me!

First of all, thank for the quick response. Now, I am not very acquainted with all this $PATH thing. When I use "bin" in line 4: ´´´COPY --from=ghcr.io/astral-sh/uv:0.5.4 /uv /uvx /bin/´´´ same thing happens. If I use /Scripts/uv its even worse because vscode highlighted it as an error.
What would a "fully qualified path" means? what "binary" should I put in the $PATH, and where should I find this $PATH. Thanks a lot and thanks for the patience.

For information about "this $PATH thing", this article or the wikipedia article are probably good places to start.


I changed the original Dockerfile, because in UV documentation the Dockerfile looks this, but I guess the bin folder only applies to IOs, and for windows its called Scripts, so I changed lines 4 and 14 from /bin to /Scripts (I don't think that's the problem)

That is absolutely the problem.
You're not running in a Windows container; you're running a Linux container. The default $PATH (the variable in which the system will search for unqualified binary names like uv) typically includes /bin, but it does not include /Scripts.
By placing the uv binary in /Scripts, you have placed it where it won't be found.

You could add /Scripts to your $PATH, and then you could run uv and it would work.
You could call it with a fully qualified path, like /Scripts/uv.

But the easiest solution is to not makes changes just for the sake of changing things: put the binaries in /bin as documented and they will work as expected.

With the following Dockerfile, everything works as expected:
FROM python:3.11

# Install uv.
COPY --from=ghcr.io/astral-sh/uv:latest /uv /uvx /bin/

# Copy the application into the container.
COPY . /app

# Install the application dependencies.
WORKDIR /app
RUN uv sync --frozen --no-cache

# Run the application.
CMD ["/app/.venv/bin/uvicorn", "src.main:app", "--port", "80", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]


ok, I keep having the same error when using the following:
Line 4 COPY --from=ghcr.io/astral-sh/uv:0.5.4 /uv /uvx /bin/
Line 14 CMD ["/app/.venv/bin/uvicorn", "run", "src.main:app", "--port", "80", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
And also when using:
Line 4: ADD https://astral.sh/uv/0.5.4/install.sh /uv-installer.sh
as UV doc also suggested. Any ideas?

I get: Exit code 127, which is maybe related to CRLF or LF terminations... which I have o clue what they are..

btw: thanks for the response!

Trying to paste log output or configuration into comments makes them difficult to read. Feel free to add additional information to your question. I've updated my answer to show a Dockerfile that works without errors when I use it. You can see the complete test environment (Dockerfile + example Python app) here.
